# changing static variable in boost thread

Tags: c++, thread-safety, boost-thread, static-members

I am using boost thread to run opengl functions and my main thread is intended to communicated with external programs through standard input and output. The reason is that once opengl enters the main loop, it never leaves but I need a way to read in inputs while not blocking to the rendering. Once the program receives inputs, the main program communicates with the opengl thread through static members (simply changing the values)

```
class ARGraphicController
{
    public:
        ARGraphicController(int sw, int sh);
        ~ARGraphicController();
        //...
        void start(int argc, char *argv[]);
        static void changeGen();
        static bool genMove;
    private:
        //..
};


bool ARGraphicController::genMove;
void ARGraphicController::start(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //opengl initialization
    //./
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

This is my main

```
void main()
{
    graphic_handler = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ARGraphicController::start, &graphic_controller, argc, argv));

    string command_line;

    while(1)
    {
        getline(cin, command_line);
        //process input command
        //...
        //...

        if(command == "genmov"){
            //change static variable to true
            graphic_controller.changeGen();
            while(1)
            {
            //until the thread change the static variable back to false
                if(!graphic_controller.genMove)
                {
                    //...
                    break;
                }       
            }
        }

    }
    delete graphic_handler;
}
```

What I don't understand is changeGen() doesn't change the value of the static variable if i do this:

```
void ARGraphicController::changeGen()
{
    genMove = true;
}
```

but when I add a std::cout, the values are changed..

```
void ARGraphicController::changeGen()
{
    genMove = true;
    std::cout<<"value is changed :)"<<std::endl;
}
```

I suspect it has to do with the fact that static member variables (essentially global variablse) is not thread safe? If so, how can I fix this problem? or is there better ways to design my application for communicating between my main and thread?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on a C++11 compiler?

Comment: I dont think i enabled c++11. I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: VS2010 does not have a switch for C++11 features, so all of the features it provides are always active. Unfortunately, most of the stuff related to threading was only introduced with VS2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [memory ordering](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic/thread_coordination.html).

The problem here is that in your current setup you get no guarantee when the written value will become visible to the other thread. Any of the compiler, the CPU, the cache or the memory controller (and possibly others) can insert optimizations here that prevent the change from becoming visible in the second thread. Apart from that, you also have a data race. Unsynchronized access to a bool will work on most modern architectures, but may break viciously on others. In ISO-C++11 such data-races immediately result in undefined behavior.

The solution is to make use of the threading library. The simplest fix here is to simply use an `atomic<bool>` for the static variable. That will take care of both ordering and access issues. Alternatively, consider one of the message passing primitives:

- Use [`boost::future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) to signal one-off events.
- Use [`boost::condition_variable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) to signal recurring conditions that threads can wait on (producer-consumer is the prominent example here)
- Use the lockfree queues from [boost.lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) to establish data streams between threads when sending lots of uniform messages.

Comment: Probably because it either changed scheduling or prevented optimization in a subtle way. The problem is that the compiler is allowed to load `graphic_controller.genMove` into a register before the loop and does not need to look at it the memory again afterwards. So your change either prevented the compiler from doing that or it changed the scheduling such that it is much more likely now that the variable will already be set before entering the loop. It is very hard to tell the causes for this kind of behavior though.

Comment: also, for using atomic classes (c++11 featuers), I think volatile variable may suffice the same purpose?

Comment: No. `volatile` does not guarantee ordering. VS2010 gives additional guarantees for `volatile`, but in ISO-C++ `volatile` is pretty much useless for threading.